# How to set Color for the text box in visual basic Word macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I tried to change background color of text box.
These are not working:

```
Me.TextBox1.ForeColor = &HFF& 
Me.TextBox1.BackColor = &H8000000D
```

I did not find any field corresponding to color. My text box:

```
Set Box = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=440, Height:=300)
Box.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not having any success with the color for your text box possibly for two reasons.

Firstly, you create your text box correctly using the shapes object but then you when you set the colour you use `Me.TextBox1`.  Since you have created the object using the `Box` variable it is better to use this variable to set the colour.

The second problem is that the `Shape` object uses the `Fill` property to set the colour.  Therefore you simply need to use the following code after creating the `Box`:

```
Box.Fill.ForeColor = &HFF&
Box.Fill.BackColor = &H8000000D
```